# Cannot compile less with attr()

Tags: django, gulp, less

I've encountered error while compiling using Gulp, tried to get count using html attribute `data-list-count` but when saved file, Gulp gave error

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] TypeError: Cannot read property 'denominator' of undefined
at Dimension.operate (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/dimension.js:87:58)
at Operation.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/operation.js:31:18)
at Expression.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/expression.js:31:37)
at Expression.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/expression.js:31:37)
at Value.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/value.js:18:30)
at Rule.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/rule.js:56:33)
at Ruleset.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:149:50)
at Ruleset.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:149:50)
at Ruleset.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:149:50)
at Ruleset.eval (/node_modules/less/lib/less/tree/ruleset.js:149:50)
```

HTML(django)

```
<ul data-list-count="4">
  <li><a href="#live-chat">{% trans "Live Chat" %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#email-marketing">{% trans "Email Marketing" %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#marketing-automation">{% trans "Marketing automation" %}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#mobile">{% trans "Mobile" %}</a></li>
</ul>
```

LESS:

```
li {
  width: (100% / attr(data-list-count));
}
```

I'm sure LESS line is causing it, but why and how to fix it ?

Comment: Try putting it within `~""` (like `width: ~"(100% / attr(data-list-count))"`). Less typically does aggressive compilation and since it doesn't have a way to know what `attr()` function's value is, it may be failing.

Comment: Now it compiles, but it's printing raw `width: (100% / attr(data-list-count));` in css, so it says it's _invalid property value_

Comment: Ok but that's expected because the `attr()` function is currently not supported in any property other than `content`. That is a browser limitation and it has nothing to do with Less.

Comment: Ah, alright. Thank you for support!

p.s. do you know any easy alternative to this ?

Comment: I've never used flexboxes much but try and see if that helps.

Comment: Ahh, yes, i could use them, i even have gridlex to for my flexbox grid, but i wanted something like use of attribute. Nevermind, i will get along with this.

Comment: You can't get the value of an HTML attribute and use it in LESS to do mathematical operations